Rank of a matrix and linear dependency of vectors building it
There is a lemma and a short algebraic proof that I was trying to get, but got confused omissions (I know that there is a direct proof without involving linear algebra).

A sum $M$ of two rank 1 matrices $M=h_1v_1u_1^T+h_2v_2u_2^T$ (where $u_i$'s and $v_i$'s are 2x1 ordinary vectors $(u_{i1},u_{i2})^T$ and $(v_{i1},v_{i2})^T$, $h_i$'s are just numbers) can only be rank 1 if either $v_i$'s are linearly dependent or $u_i$'s are linearly dependent.

The proof started with an assumption that $u_i$'s are linearly independent. (*) Then the image of $M$ is spanned by the vectors $M(u_1)$ and $M(u_2)$ which are both linear combinations of $h_1v_1$ and $h_2v_2$.
(**) Then, if the matrix of coefficients
$$G=\begin{bmatrix} u_1^Tu_1 && u_1^Tu_2 \\ u_2^Tu_1 && u_2^Tu_2 \end{bmatrix}$$ is invertible, then image of $M$ is the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$.
My question is in how the steps (*) and (**) were followed.
The matrix $M$ in general can be represented as $$ M=h_1 \begin{bmatrix} v_{11}u_{11} && v_{11}u_{12} \\ v_{12}u_{11} && v_{12}u_{12} \end{bmatrix} + h_2 \begin{bmatrix} v_{21}u_{21} && v_{21}u_{22} \\ v_{22}u_{21} && v_{22}u_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$  but what are $M(u_1)$ and $M(u_2)$ are a bit unclear. Maybe $M(u_i)=h_1v_1u_i^T+h_2v_2u_i^T$ in which case $$M(u_1)=\Big(h_1\begin{bmatrix} v_{11} \\ v_{12} \end{bmatrix}+h_2\begin{bmatrix} v_{21} \\ v_{22} \end{bmatrix}\Big)\cdot \begin{bmatrix} u_{11} && u_{12} \end{bmatrix} $$ and similarly for $M(u_2)$. But in what sense $M$ is spanned by vectors $M(u_1)$ and $M(u_2)$ which are linear combinations of $h_1v_1$ and $h_2v_2$ if they are in different vector spaces.
Regarding the second point, where does the matrix come from and what's the argument inside.
Thanks in advance for any comments or answers.

There are some issues here as you don't state the field involved (probably reals) and your vectors are artificially limited to having two components. [Also the statement is flawed as it should state $h_1\neq 0$ and $h_2\neq 0$.]
But the result actually holds over any field with $\mathbf u_i, \mathbf v_i \in \mathbb K^n$ for $n\geq 2$.  The proof you are trying to follow breaks in general, e.g. $\mathbb K :=\mathbb F_3$ set $n=6$ and $\mathbf u_1 = \mathbf v_1 = \sum_{k=1}^3 \mathbf e_k$ and $\mathbf u_2 =\mathbf v_2=\mathbf 1$ and $h_1=1=h_2$.  Then $\text{rank}\big(M\big)=2$ but $G=\mathbf 0$ and $\big\{M\mathbf u_1, M\mathbf u_2\big\}=\big\{\mathbf 0\big\}$ doesn't generate the span of $M$.
A better proof:
$M=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c}
 \mathbf v_1 & \mathbf v_2
\end{array}\bigg]D\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf u_1^T \\
 \mathbf u_{2}^T
\end{bmatrix}= VDU^T$
where $D$ is diagonal with $h_1,h_2$ as diagonal components, each non-zero.
Now if $V$ and $U^T$ are rank 2 then $V$ is injective and $U^T$ is surjective so let $Y, X^T$ be their respective left and right inverses.  Submultiplicativity of rank tells us
$2=\text{rank}\big(D\big)=\text{rank}\big((YV)D(U^TX^T)\big)\leq\text{rank}\big(VDU^T\big)=\text{rank}\big(M\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(D\big)$
i.e. it tells you $V$ and $U$ being rank 2 is sufficient for $M$ to have rank 2
And it is necessary because
$\text{rank}\big(M\big)\leq \min\big(\text{rank}(V), \text{rank}(D),\text{rank}(U)\big)$.
$\implies\text{rank}\big(M\big)=1\implies \min\big(\text{rank}(V),\text{rank}(U)\big)=1$
